# How can I stop Windows mouse jitter but maintain fast speed?

Tags: windows-7, mouse

I have not had a steady mouse since early in the Windows 7 days.  I'm looking for advice on possible configurations or solutions to this issue, not so much what brand of mouse to buy.

I've tried corded laser gaming mice with high dpi, I've tried cordless "optical" (which I assume is maybe infra-red or some invisible laser, not sure) mice.

I've tried smooth pads, no pads, shiny pads, dark, light, all sorts of things below the mouse.

I've fiddled with all of the settings, speeds, acceleration, etc, and still I could not trace the arrow point along a straight line to save my life.  And I have steady hands. Even with a perfectly smooth pad, I trace as slowly as I can but it's almost like the mouse sprite is travelling over bumps or getting snagged on a sweater or something--while the mouse itself is on a perfectly smooth pad.

I do a fair amount of photo editing in Lightroom and I do recall days when I could very easily and accurately select pixels, but I have a hard time even re-sizing windows because it's so hard to get the mouse to land on a window border.  Again--it's not that I've gotten older or have the shakes--this is either a hardware or software issue and I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas as to what might be causing this?

I currently have a Logitech Corded M-500, which is fairly inexpensive and pedestrian, but I also had tried a big-bucks Microsoft Sidewinder gaming mouse with all sorts of controls, and too many in-between to mention, but still the jitter.

Comment: My thinking is the higher dpi, the more likely the jitter, as it's more sensitive.

Comment: Hardware recommendations are off-topic. // You may have used a mouse with "angle snapping" before. Some have explicit support for this feature and it can be tweaked to suit your tastes.

Comment: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ - Hardware Requests should go here.

Comment: Thanks, yes I was on the fence about where to post but it's not necessarily a hardware rec (though I added that tag), I'm actually hoping someone might have heard, say, that cordless phone interference or something along those lines could cause that behavior.  Or maybe that laser mice need dark pads and infra-red mice need light pads, or something more general.   One thing that fixed an even bigger jitter issue when using RDP was turning off the Windows Aero Theme from the Mouse Pointers dialog.  That worked for the target RDP machine which was getting "double-jitter" but not on my own.

Comment: Please remove the hardware-rec tag else your question will attract close votes. Also consider explicitly stating in the Q that you're not asking for hardware recommendations and emphasize that you're asking *if anyone has any ideas as to what might be causing this?* (It's a bit buried in there.)

Comment: Close voters: Please notice the 2nd sentence: *I'm looking for advice on possible configurations or solutions to this issue, not so much what brand of mouse to buy.*

Comment: Maybe consider snapping a little video using something like [ShareX](https://getsharex.com/) to make it more clear what you're facing. Lower DPI and higher Windows Mouse Setting speed is what I'd try.

Comment: I've tried High-speed + Low DPI and Low-speed + High DPI and they both seem the same.  I'm assuming it's like bicycle gears where different front/rear sprocket combos result in the same final ratio.   Anyway I think I my just resign to conclude simply that my memory of a smoother mouse was back when I had a smaller monitor and 1024x768 screen.  Now at 1920x1200 tracing a line across the screen is nearly twice as many pixels, and to compensate my mouse speed is faster and therefore more prone to jitter.  I can be accurate if I slow the mouse way down--though that means more pad-cycles.